# Append Characters to list item if its found in another list

Tags: python, list, append

I have two lists, one of the form:

```
lst = [">ctgxxxx1/n", "aatttata", ">ctgxxxx2/n", "attggag", ">ctgxxxx3/n", "ggagttata"]
```

and another of the form

```
ATP6 = [ ">ctgxxxx1/n", ">ctgxxxx3/n"]
```

For every item in `lst` that is also found in `ATP6` I want to append "ATP6" to the end of the item in `lst`. In this example I would like the output of the code to be:

```
lst = [">ctgxxxx1ATP6/n", "aatttata", ">ctgxxxx2/n", "attggag", ">ctgxxxx3ATP6/n", "ggagttata"]
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
for x in lst:
    if x.startswith(">"):
        if x in ATP6:
            x = x+"ATP6"
```

This however isnt having any effect at all.

I assume its not working because I have a nested if statement but Im not sure. As well as an answer could I have an explanation of why my code doesnt work to help me learn. Thankyou!

Comment: This has been asked many times, but it's hard to find the dup. Problem is you're changing variable `x` not the original list item. Iterate over indices and change the item using its  index. It would have been a different scenario if list contained mutable objects and you performed in-place operation on `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, as mentioned in the comments, is because you're modifying a copy of the element in your array, not the original.
Additionally, you can shorten your code to a more pythonic list comprehension like so:

```
lst = [x+'ATP6' if x in ATP6 else x for x in lst]
```

Comment: Thankyou, is there any way i could put the "ATP6" before the new line symbol (currently when I implement this and print to file I get the ctgxxxx newline then ATP6) or would I have to find /nATP6 and replace with ATP6/n?

Comment: You could use `x[:-1]+"ATP6"`. In general I'd suggest not having control characters until you need them.

Comment: You could use `x.replace('\n', 'ATP6\n')` instead of `x+'ATP6'` IF you're sure every element in lst ends with a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not do what you want because you attempt to modify an immutable type (string) in your loop. This will create a new object instead of changing the sting in place.

I'd use a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [lstitem+'ATP6' if lstitem in ATP6 else lstitem for lstitem in lst]
```

yields:

```
['>ctgxxxx1/nATP6',
 'aatttata',
 '>ctgxxxx2/n',
 'attggag',
 '>ctgxxxx3/nATP6',
 'ggagttata']
```